# How to keep track of Telegram group chat_id

Tags: telegram-bot, python-telegram-bot

I have been implementing a Telegram bot using [python-telegram-bot](https://docs.python-telegram-bot.org/en/v20.5).

I want to link each group with a Google Sheet file
(by having a look up table {chat_id, sheetName}) pairs.

I tried to make use of the `chat_id` to identify each group and find its corresponding sheet, but I found out that `chat_id` changes in certain conditions. Because of this, I lost track of this group.

I want a way to figure out when the id changes, and update the lookup table old id with the new id.

How can I do that? I want this to happen automatically.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: Please have a look at https://github.com/python-telegram-bot/python-telegram-bot/wiki/Storing-bot%2C-user-and-chat-related-data#chat-migration